# Sort words alphabetically but "ch" is more than "h" using qsort with saving it as upper case

Tags: c++, sorting

I just cant figure out, how to sort a char array (NO VECTOR) of words alphabetically.  Because our alphabet has "ch" which is "bigger" than "h", so I need every word starting with "ch" go behind "h".

This is mine current code of sorting, but i cant fogure it out, how to add "ch more than h" rule.

And im using here "everything compare and save as upper" policy, because mine bigger project need it.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char *one = *(char **) b;
    one = to_uppercase(one);
    char *two = *(char **) a;
    two = to_uppercase(two);
    return strcmp(one , two);
}

void sortit(char **list, int lenght) {
    qsort(list, lenght, sizeof(char *), compare);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your only sorting requirement "lexicographically, except `ch` comes at the end"?

Comment: Do you only want to sort them by the *first* character in the words?

Comment: when you say "our language" - which language is that? Are you supposed to sort these according to their translated strings?

Comment: ...if it weren't for that horse...

Comment: need a proper problem statement

Comment: The language that used to have `ch` as a single letter is Spanish.  Are you trying to sort Spanish words?

Comment: should "ch" always be treated as a single digraph, or only when it forms the "ch" sound? For example, would "ichor" be treated as `i-c-h-o-r` or `i-ch-o-r`?

Comment: What if `ch` is in the middle of a word?  And what letter comes after `ch`?

Comment: I think @JohnFilleau has the better option than trying to actually sort the original strings.  Some sort of mapping from the original string to the "canonicalized" string, and then the canonicalized string is easily sorted.

Comment: My wife also suggests *chimera* as a c-h word that doesn't have the "ch" sound. But now I'm wondering if the c-h in *chimera* and *ichor* should be its own digraph separate from the c-h in *chimney* and *church*. And does the hard-k c-h evaluate equal to k in sorting? Are we... are we sorting phonetically? This question is breaking my brain.

Comment: StayPositive69, Requirements talk about `ch`, yet example is `Ch`.  Are you looking for a case insensitive sort too in addition to the `ch` as just-past-`h` compare? If case insensitive, is `_` (which is between upper/lower case) before or after all letters?

Comment: The implementation that would be easiest to understand assuming any occurance of `ch` is treated as single char is probrobably a function that takes one "token" at a time given a reference to an iterator and the end operator (e.g. `int GetToken(std::string::const_iterator& pos, std::string::const_iterator end);`); In that case all basically comes down to implementing a lexicographical compare on the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define your own comparison function.

**[IMPORTANT]** Notice this solution only looks at the first character. I.e. "aching" and "advert" will be ordered as ["aching", "advert"], and not as ["advert", "aching"], even when 'ch' should come after 'd'.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1Tfzh8xd8)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // sort
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "apple", "car", "cherry", "hugo", "boss" };

    auto my_words_cmp = [](auto& w1, auto& w2) {
        if (w1.size() > 1 and w2.size() > 0 and w1.substr(0, 2) == "ch" and w2[0] <= 'h') { return false; }
        else if (w1.size() > 0 and w2.size() > 1 and w1[0] <= 'h' and w2.substr(0, 2) == "ch") { return true; }
        else return (w1 < w2);
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), my_words_cmp);

    for (auto& w : words) { std::cout << w << " "; }
}

// Outputs
//   apple boss car hugo cherry
```

---

**[EDIT]** Taking into account the comments from other users, here's an implementation that sorts the strings taking into account that 'ch' can appear anywhere:

- Walk each input word (if any of them contains a 'ch'; otherwise compare them straight away and return).
- Map each character, including 'ch', to an int value: 0 for 'a', 8 for 'h', 9 for 'ch', 10 for 'i'...
- Then compare the two vectors.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/6x9s9sK9s)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // sort, transform
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "aching", "advert", "m", "d", "ch", "a" };

    auto my_words_cmp = [](auto& w1, auto& w2) {
        if (w1.find("ch") == std::string::npos and w2.find("ch") == std::string::npos) { return w1 < w2; }
        std::vector<int> v1(w1.size());
        std::vector<int> v2(w2.size());
        auto weight_char = [](auto& c1, auto& c2) {
                if (c1 == 'c' and c2 == 'h') { return 'h' - 'a' + 1; }
                else if (c1 <= 'h') { return c1 - 'a'; }
                else { return c1 - 'a' + 1; }
        };
        std::transform(std::begin(w1), std::end(w1), std::next(std::begin(w1)), std::begin(v1), weight_char);
        std::transform(std::begin(w2), std::end(w2), std::next(std::begin(w2)), std::begin(v2), weight_char);
        return v1 < v2;
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), my_words_cmp);

    for (auto& w : words) { std::cout << w << " "; }
}

// Outputs:
//    advert aching d ch m
```

Comment: Correct as long as the weird sorting requirement isn't a typo. But the best we can do is take the problem as stated at face value.

Comment: I have to say I haven't tested the solution much either; but I just hope the OP will get the idea :)

Comment: It's strict weak ordering *at least* in the case where the entire set is only these five words. I went cross-eyed trying to figure out if there's an edge case. A jokier answer would assign a numeric value to the five words and sort on that :)

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yeah assuming you would map 'ch' to a single number that would work too. ;)

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didnt show it precisely. You are using vectors, but im using charlist. Im sorting it via quick sort, but i dont know how to use your compare function with quick sort. I will edit my post ofc. Thanks

Comment: @StayPositive69 You are using `qsort`, not quick sort.  There is no guarantee whatsoever that `qsort` uses the quick sort algorithm.  In any event, you're using C++, so why not use `std::sort`?

Comment: @StayPositive69 Just create a function accepting a `std::vector<std::string> words` and feed it with your char arrays. The body of the function would basically be my `main` code without the print at teh bottom.